# Problems with form controls in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project and I am trying to add checks for the inputs on the form. I want it to only submit and move to the URL if the requirements are met. I'm using Javascript to check this. Currently, my code doesn't return any errors in the console but when I press submit even with blank inputs it submits and moves to the next page.

```js
// Form Controls

const form = document.getElementById('form');
const username = document.getElementById('username');
const room = document.getElementById('room');

// Show input error message
function showError(input, message) {
  const formControl = input.parentElement;
  formControl.className = 'form-control error';
  const small = formControl.querySelector('small');
  small.innerText = message;
}

// Show Success outline
function showSuccess(input) {
  const formControl = input.parentElement;
  formControl.className = 'form-control success';
}


// Check required fields
function checkRequired(inputArr) {
  inputArr.forEach(function(input) {
    if (input.value.trim() === '') {
      showError(input, `${getFieldName(input)} is required`);
    } else {
      showSuccess(input);
    }
  });
}

// Get fieldName
function getFieldName(input) {
  return input.id.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + input.id.slice(1);
}

// Event Listeners

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  checkRequired([username]);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="../static/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>ChatR</title>
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='scripts.js') }}"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-head">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>MyApp</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <form action="{{url_for('chat') }}" class="form" id="form" method="POST">

      <div class="form-control">

        <input type="username" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter username">
        <small>Error Message</small>
      </div>
      <div class="form-control">

        <input type="room" id="room" name="room" placeholder="Enter room">
        <small>Error Message</small>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-big">Start Chat</button>
    </form>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

New Code that works:

```
// Check required fields
function checkRequired(inputArr) {
  var success = true;
    inputArr.forEach(function(input) {
      if (input.value.trim() === '') {
        success = false;
        showError(input, `${getFieldName(input)} is required`);
      } else {
        showSuccess(input);
      }
    });
    return success;
  }  
  // Check input length
function checkLength(input, min, max) {
  var success = true;
    if(input.value.length < min) {
      showError(input, `${getFieldName(input)} must be at least ${min} characters`);
      console.log(input);
      success = false;
    } else if(input.value.length > max) {
      showError(input, `${getFieldName(input)} must be less than ${max} characters`);
      success = false;
    } else {
      showSuccess(input);
    }
    return success;
  }

  
  // Get fieldName
  function getFieldName(input) {
    return input.id.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + input.id.slice(1);
  }
  
  // Event Listeners
  
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    if(checkRequired([username, room]) && checkLength(username, 3, 15)){
      form.submit();
    }      
          
   
  });
```

Comment: I just made your code runnable, and I don't see your mentioned problem. The validation is working properly. @robothead

Comment: Strange, Im not getttng that. If I hit submit with empty input it just goes to the next page set in the form action. This is a Flask project by the way.

Comment: You haven't shown any "logic" regarding form submission ... the code you posted doesn't submit at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some changes to the code so it submits when it is successful.

The first thing is to have `checkRequired` return `true` or `false` indicating if the validation was successful or not.

Second, check that value in the submit event listener and submit the form if it is valid.

```
// Check required fields, returning true/false if valid.
function checkRequired(inputArr) {
  var success = true; // <= assume success
  inputArr.forEach(function(input) {
    if (input.value.trim() === '') {
      success = false; // <= if anything fails, the not successful
      showError(input, `${getFieldName(input)} is required`);
    } else {
      showSuccess(input);
    }
  });
  return success; // return value indicating success
}

// Event Listeners

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // submit only if validation is successful
  if(checkRequired([username, room])){
    form.submit();
  }
});
```

By the way, you might want to add `room` to the array of inputs being validated.

Comment: Hey thanks for this, Im still having issues though. I added your code and now I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') Another poster mentioned adding : document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {  }); that stopped the error but then nothing happens when I click submit.

Comment: You were already doing `form.addEventListener` and I did not change that in my code example so it should have worked just like before. My code above is meant to "replace" your functions in your code as opposed to be "added"... Can you double check that?

Comment: hi, by adding I meant replacing my code with yours. I tried that and I get that error

Comment: in your code after you return success then what do you do with that variable?

Comment: Im not sure exactly what changed, but instead of copying and replacing my code with yours I just added in those success variables and the if statement and now it works. Also when I move the script to the bottom of the HTML file then I don't need that  DOMContentLoaded, I also added another rule and it seems to work good now. Thank you for return true or false in the form of a variable I edited the code to show my new code. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is Because the element is not  found in the DOM while the script is running with this it will run after dom gets loaded.
So solution for this is to add a this line on top of scripts.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

//whole scripts.js in this section

//ends with this
})
```

with this it will loads and check if DOM is loaded or not and after that your script will work

Comment: This code will run when u use  <script src="scripts.js"></script> ..there is problem related to <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js') }}"></script> this ..You can got on this for future use of this ..hope it helps !! https://grabthiscode.com/whatever/script-src-url_for-static-filename-scripts-js-script